# Normalize XML text node in Python minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I want to insert this string:

```
No, on the 5<Font Script="super">th</Font>
```

as a Text Node in XML by xml.dom.minidom createTextNode(), however, after I writexml() to a file, the signs:

```
< > "
```

turns to:

```
No, on the 5&lt;Font Script=&quot;super&quot;&gt;th&lt;/Font&gt;
```

How can I avoid this? Thanks.

A part of my code:

```
impl = minidom.getDOMImplementation()
dom = impl.createDocument(None, None, None)
TextTextNode = dom.createTextNode(text.decode("utf-8"))
Text = dom.createElement("Text")
Text.appendChild(TextTextNode)
fileToWrite =  codecs.open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
dom.writexml(fileToWrite, indent=" ", addindent=" ", newl="\n", encoding='utf-8')
fileToWrite.close()
```

There is a sample for this by the cinecanvase specification:

```
<Text HAlign=”left” HPosition=”10.2” VAlign=”bottom” VPosition=”10.0”> This <Font Script=”super”>word </Font>is superscript </Text >
```

I need insert the  `<Font>..</Font>`  into another element, the .

Comment: Is the 'Font' thing supposed to be an XML attribute? Could you post a complete XML sample of what you want to get? (verified using: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp )

Comment: @BorrajaX actually, it is a digital cinema subtitle xml standard, its specification is here: http://www.dlp.com/downloads/pdf_dlp_cinema_cinecanvas_rev_c.pdf , and the sample for that is like: <Text HAlign=”left” HPosition=”10.2” VAlign=”bottom” 
VPosition=”10.0”> This <Font Script=”super”>word </Font>is 
superscript </Text >

Comment: I find the answer from this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623607/escaping-and-in-xml-when-using-xml-dom-minidom

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that format, but that  thing looks like an XML node. Try this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import codecs

output = "test.xml"
text="No, on the 5"


impl = minidom.getDOMImplementation()
dom = impl.createDocument(None, None, None)
FontNode = dom.createElement("Font")
FontNode.setAttribute('Script', 'super')
FontNode.appendChild(dom.createTextNode('th'))
Text = dom.createElement("Text")
TextTextNode = dom.createTextNode(text.decode("utf-8"))
Text.appendChild(TextTextNode)
Text.appendChild(FontNode)
fileToWrite =  codecs.open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
Text.writexml(fileToWrite, indent=" ", addindent=" ", newl="\n")
fileToWrite.close()
```

That outputs:

```
 <Text>
  No, on the 5
  <Font Script="super">th</Font>
 </Text>
```

Be aware that what you want to write a tree in a file (when you call [writexml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.writexml)) you need to call the `writexml` method with your XML's tree root (you were calling it with `dom`, not with your root node)